# How to make a simple autocomplete searchbox that gets data from database?

Tags: search, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete, autosuggest

I am bit of a noob when it comes to `jQuery` and `MySQL`... I have seen some of the tutorials, but I can't figure out how I have to combine the things with my database. For instance, I have a table (?) with all my topics in it that I have called "TOPICS" in my database. What I want is that if someone uses the searchbox, that they will get suggestions that are in these TOPICS.

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

This is a very simple autocomplete that I want to use. I can make it with local suggestions, but I don't know how to combine it with my `database`. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are after (well, it's what I would do anyway):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      <?php
        require "connect.php"; //connect to your database
        $select = "
          SELECT topicname
          FROM topics
          ORDER BY topicname
        ";
        $query = mysqli_query($link, $select);
        if(!$query) die("Error: " . mysqli_error($link) . "\nMySQL: " . $select); //for trouble shooting purposes
        while($array = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
          echo '"' . $array['topicname'] . '",';
        }
      ?>
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="ui-widget">
 <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
 <input id="tags" />
</div>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The autocomplete provides an example: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

```
$( "#city" ).autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    data: {
                        featureClass: "P",
                        style: "full",
                        maxRows: 12,
                        name_startsWith: request.term
                    },
                    success: function( data ) {
                        response( $.map( data.geonames, function( item ) {
                            return {
                                label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
                                value: item.name
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 2,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                log( ui.item ?
                    "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
                    "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
            },
            open: function() {
                $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
            },
            close: function() {
                $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
            }
        });
```

Comment: That has no database (MYSQL) or whatsoever mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect directly from Javascript to MySQL. You need a php file, jsp file or similar that fetches the results from the database and returns them to the autocompletion. Look at http://www.htmlblog.us/jquery-autocomplete for a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of connecting to MySQL through REST frontend, I think it makes sense to look at 3rd party solution such as www.rockitsearch.com. It has the basic autocomplete functionality out of the box. All you need to do is register, export your data and integrate a widget to your web site. All the rest of the work will be done for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I think an Ajax call to a PHP script that returns JSON formatted list of first 10 avail answers, based on the search input text value, and displaying from Javascript ( inside the Ajax call function ) in a DIV, below the searchbox, the values that are selectable / clickable.